# Is there a way to monitor a gmail inbox for changes?

Tags: alert, monitoring, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsublite

I'm looking for a way to monitor a gmail inbox and alert if a specific email is not received by end of day. the account is not user-owned (its a business email dedicated to this purpose) So I need a way to make this work without being "logged in" with a stored token(authorization can be granted the first time. or once every couple of months if needed).

I've checked out Pub/Sub but not sure if its relevant for my use-case or if its a bit of an overkill since I need only this one specific thing

Comment: Why does it need to be continuous? If the goal is to alert if an email doesn't arrive by end of day then you should be able to just check *at end of day*.

Comment: @Quentin you're right, that part was confusing, I removed it. What I meant was that there should be no need for any action on the part of the monitored account. It can be a cron that runs once a day, polls the email and then alerts, but I think in in this scenario the email needs to be logged in somewhere with a token stored

Comment: So what's the *specific* problem you are having? The API documentation looks pretty good and covers logging in and searching for a variety of programming languages.

Comment: you can use pub sub it will be easier if this is a workspace domain user